# How can I parse XML using JSON

Tags: iphone, xml, json

Sorry for my question. Actually I didnt knew about the JSON, I want to parse the XML file by some new technique. Can anyone help?

Comment: Huh? XML and JSON are data formats. You don't parse one... using the other...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant parse XML using JSON, since both are data formats. In other words they cant be used to parse each other, since they are only data "containers", that means that their only purpose is to give data a specific format.

If you want to parse XML, you use a XML parser.
If you want to parse JSON you use a JSON parser.

Comment: @:Wifi Cordon: Thanks for ur help and clarification

Answer (score 15):

In the same way that apples and oranges are both eaten, yet one fruit does not eat the other.

Comment: One does say to the other, "You're an apple!"

Comment: You deserve as many +1s as possible. But let's also help the guy.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to change the question wording, but the answer probably is this:
http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/ (also on github https://github.com/stig/json-framework/)

Kickstarter: http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/